# How do I replace all strings in a list with one of any substrings?

Tags: string-manipulation

So, for example I have

```
StringReplace[
  {"abc", "abd", "abx", "abf", "abe", "abg", "abh", "abi", "acb", "acd"}, 
  {"bd" -> "", "bg" -> ""}]
```

which gives

```
{"abc", "a", "abx", "abf", "abe", "a", "abh", "abi", "acb", "acd"},
```

but I want the new list to be

```
{"abc", "abx", "abf", "abe", "abh", "abi", "acb", "acd"}.
```

A solution is alright if it works for the fact that I am starting with a list of sub-lists with the same length and deleting everything else. I tried using an if statement with by splitting into characters and using delete, but for some reason this didn't work.

Comment: does this give ehat you need: `DeleteCases[{"abc", "abd", "abx", "abf", "abe", "abg", "abh", "abi", 
  "acb", "acd"}, _?(StringMatchQ[#, "*bd" | "*bg"] &)]`?

Comment: Select[{"abc", "abd", "abx", "abf", "abe", "abg", "abh", "abi", "acb",
   "acd"}, ! StringContainsQ[#, {"bd", "bg"}] &]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strngs = {"abc", "abd", "abx", "abf", "abe", "abg", "abh", "abi",  "acb", "acd"}; 

Pick[strngs, ! StringMatchQ[#, "*bd*" | "*bg*"] & /@   strngs]
```

> {"abc", "abx", "abf", "abe", "abh", "abi", "acb", "acd"}

Answer (score 4):

```
lst = {"abc", "abd", "abx", "abf", "abe", "abg", "abh", "abi", "acb", "acd"}
fn = Pick[#, StringFreeQ[#, #2]] &;


fn[lst, "bd" | "bg"]
```

> {"abc", "abx", "abf", "abe", "abh", "abi", "acb", "acd"}

```
fn[lst, "bd" | "ac" | "bc"]
```

> {"abx", "abf", "abe", "abg", "abh", "abi"}

Etc...

Comment: +1 Similar: `Select[lst, StringFreeQ["bd" | "bg"]]` or `Cases[lst, _?(StringFreeQ["bd" | "bg"])]`

Answer (score 1):

Replacing works too:

```
Replace[_?(StringContainsQ["bd" | "bg"]) -> Sequence[]] /@
{"abc", "abd", "abx", "abf", "abe", "abg", "abh", "abi", "acb", "acd"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`StringDelete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringDelete.html)

```
data = {"abc", "abd", "abx", "abf", "abe", "abg", "abh", "abi", "acb", "acd"};
StringDelete[data, {_ ~~ "bd", _ ~~ "bg"}] // DeleteCases[""]
```

> `{"abc", "abx", "abf", "abe", "abh", "abi", "acb", "acd"}`

An alternative is

```
StringDelete[data, (_ ~~ "bd") | (_ ~~ "bg")] // DeleteCases[""]
```